# Why is there not a hyphen between "natural" and "language" in the phrase "natural language processing"?

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Natural language processing is a field of AI that deals with tasks related to processing *natural languages* such as English and Spanish, in order to understand and extract data from them. Based on my understanding, the processing is done on a language which is natural and not on a language in a natural manner (possibly opposed to an artificial manner); thus, there should be a hyphen between *natural* and *language*, making it "natural-language processing"), yet I have never seen it being written like this. In a similar manner, the phrase "observation coding system" does not have a hyphen, and in a somewhat similar way, there is no hyphen used when writing phrases including words such as *approach* and *method*; phrases such as "oil processing method" and "law practice approach."

Comment: An open compound doesn't take a hyphen. Compare *high school transcript* — no hyphen.

Comment: Who decides which compounds are open and which ones are not?

Comment: Hyphen police maybe? Not me. But I know one when I see one. [Compound Words](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/)

Comment: Are "oil processing" and "law practice" compound words?

Comment: @TinfoilHat - "Hyphen police" - they usually dash to the scene of any transgression.

Comment: “In general, any compound that’s rarely hyphenated in real life can remain unhyphenated as a phrasal adjective if the meaning remains clear without the hyphen. This goes double for any compound that’s listed in a dictionary without the hyphen.” — [*Chicago Manual of Style*](https://bit.ly/2Rl882I). *Natural language* is in the dictionary. In *law practice approach*, no one would mistake *law* as modifying *practice approach*. In *oil processing method*, *oil* **could** be understood to modify *processing method* (cf. *banana processing method*) — so it doesn’t matter.